# MySQL / PHP - Conversation System

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, message

I'm having a really hard time figuring this one out. I am trying to make a conversation system and it would work like this:

A logged in user would have a link to "conversations". On that page a list of all conversation.titles would show up. When a conversation-name is clicked the conversation messages (mostly between 2 users, but could be more) will show up like this:

### Conversation tiltle...

|------------------------------------------------------------|
|Send-button| Textfield for new message here  |
|----------------|-------------------------------------------|

Sender: Hi.......                       (08/24/11 - 12PM)

receiver: Hi!.....                      (08/24/11 - 11PM

Sender: bla blah...                     (08/24/11 - 10PM)

etc..

I have no problem listing messages in the conversation itself, but rather getting the list of conversations a user participates in.

I get multiple results of the same instance.

I would like a query that produces a list of all conversations a logged in user has participated in either by sending a message, recieving a message or both.

I guess i would need a nested query, but i dont know how to do that. So i'm a bit stuck here, trying to inner-join all tables doesnt cut the cheese.

This is the [database](/questions/tagged/database) [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) design / ER-modell:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- Table `firm`.`conversation`

-- -----------------------------------------------------

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `firm`.`conversation` (

  `conversation_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,

  `title` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,

  `date` TIMESTAMP NULL ,

  PRIMARY KEY (`subject_id`) )

ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- Table `firm`.`message`

-- -----------------------------------------------------

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `firm`.`message` (

  `message_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,

  `message` LONGTEXT NULL ,

  `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,

  `read_sender` BINARY NOT NULL ,

  `read_receiver` BINARY NOT NULL ,

  `deleted_receiver` BINARY NOT NULL ,

  `deleted_sender` BINARY NOT NULL ,

  `conversation_id` INT NOT NULL ,

  PRIMARY KEY (`message_id`) ,

  INDEX `fk_message_subject1` (`subject_id` ASC) ,

  CONSTRAINT `fk_message_con1`

    FOREIGN KEY (`conversation_id` )

    REFERENCES `firm`.`conversation` (`conversation_id` )

    ON DELETE NO ACTION

    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

ENGINE = InnoDB

DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1

COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci;
```

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- Table `firm`.`outbox`

-- -----------------------------------------------------

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `firm`.`outbox` (

  `outbox_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,

  `user_id` INT(10) NOT NULL ,

  `conversation_id` INT(10) NOT NULL ,

  `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,

  PRIMARY KEY (`outbox_id`) ,

  INDEX `fk_outbox_users1` (`user_id` ASC) ,

  INDEX `fk_utbox_con1` (`conversation_id` ASC) ,

  CONSTRAINT `fk_outbox_users1`

    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id` )

    REFERENCES `firm`.`users` (`user_id` )

    ON DELETE NO ACTION

    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,

  CONSTRAINT `fk_outbox_con1`

    FOREIGN KEY (`conversation_id` )

    REFERENCES `firm`.`conversation` (`conversation_id` )

    ON DELETE NO ACTION

    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

ENGINE = InnoDB
```

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- Table `firm`.`inbox`

-- -----------------------------------------------------

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `firm`.`inbox` (

  `inbox_id` INT NOT NULL ,

  `user_id` INT(10) NOT NULL ,

  `message_id` INT NOT NULL ,

  `read` BINARY NOT NULL ,

  `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,

  PRIMARY KEY (`inbox_id`) ,

  INDEX `fk_inbox_users1` (`user_id` ASC) ,

  INDEX `fk_inbox_message` (`message_id` ASC) ,

  CONSTRAINT `fk_inbox_users1`

    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id` )

    REFERENCES `firm`.`users` (`user_id` )

    ON DELETE NO ACTION

    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,

  CONSTRAINT `fk_inbox_message1`

    FOREIGN KEY (`message_id` )

    REFERENCES `frim`.`message` (`message_id` )

    ON DELETE NO ACTION

    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT conversation.conversation_id
FROM conversation
INNER JOIN message ON message.conversation_id = conversation.conversation_id
INNER JOIN inbox   ON inbox.message_id = message.message_id
INNER JOIN outbox  ON inbox.message_id = message.message_id
WHERE outbox.user_id = #USER# 
OR    inbox.user_id = #USER#
```

This join should work. `DISTINCT` because a user is likely to have participated as a sender and a recipient.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply, I'm at work now but I will try it as soon as I get home. It looks promising!

Comment: Hi, cularis! Your method doesn't seem to work, i get the same result regardless of which user_id I use.

Comment: Could you post some sample data?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT conversation.conversation_id   FROM conversation INNER JOIN message ON message.conversation_id = conversation.conversation_id   INNER JOIN inbox ON inbox.message_id = message.message_id   INNER JOIN outbox ON outbox.conversation_id = message.conversation_id   WHERE outbox.user_id =#USER#   OR inbox.user_id = #USER#`

Comment: sorry, i don't know how to format it properly :( But that query seemed to work

Comment: I meant, could you edit in some sample data into your post. The data in your tables you are running the query against. Sorry for being unprecise.